# Upright punctuation independent from font style

Tags: punctuation, roman, mathtime

Is there any way to make all the punctuation (comma, period, colon, semicolon, etc.) in roman even if the current active style is *italic*? I am using `mathtime` package and fonts for my setup and the tags are mentioned below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\itshape Cool animals: Wombat, Capybara; Duck and Dove (no Pigeons).
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't have `mathtime`, but doesn't loading `times` (which is deprecated) kicking all that `mathtime`  does in the butt?

Comment: Wouldn't what you want look terrible?

Comment: Since your example doesn't use any math, why did you set the tag `mathtime`? Separately, the `mathtime` package is seriously obsolete. Shouldn't one be using the `mtpro2` ("MathTime Professional II") package these days?

Comment: @Johannes_B -- it's actually traditional to use upright punctuation in theorems, in particular parentheses.  at ams, there was once an attempt to create a "theorem font" that would have this property, but that was before computer memory got large enough to handle an "expanded" implementation of tex, so nothing came of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(copy of my answer on c.t.t.)

It is possible with a virtual font: You can create one that takes
its punctuation symbols from the roman font. With pdflatex it would need a few hours work (more if you also want to fine tune the kerning) and some knowledge about fonts in general and fontinst in particular. With lualatex is could be done a bit
faster.

You can also make the punctuations symbols active and define them to
switch to \upshape. But be aware that this is dangerous -- you can
break other commands. E.g. period and dot are often used in numbers.

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage[T1,mtbold]{mathtime}
 \usepackage{times}
  \defineshorthand{.}{\textup{.}}
  \defineshorthand{,}{\textup{,}}
  \defineshorthand{;}{\textup{;}}

 \useshorthands*{,}
 \useshorthands*{.}
 \useshorthands*{;}
 \begin{document}
 \itshape abc, abc; abc.

 \shorthandoff{,}\shorthandoff{.}\shorthandoff{;}
  abc, abc; abc.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use the LuaTeX `post_linebreak_filter` for that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function table.contains(t, k)
    for _, v in pairs(t) do
        if v == k then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

function upright_punctucation(head)
    -- Traverse vertical list
    for line in node.traverse_id(node.id("hhead"),head) do
       -- Traverse horizontal list
       for glyph in node.traverse_id(node.id("glyph"), line.head) do
           -- Check if the glyph is
           --                   (   )   ,   :   ;
           if (table.contains({ 40, 41, 44, 58, 59 }, glyph.char)) then
               -- and change its font to upright.
               -- (this is not so generic, 15 just happens to be upright)
               glyph.font = 15
           end
       end
    end
    return head
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",upright_punctucation,"upright_punctucation")
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
\itshape Cool animals: Wombat, Capybara; Duck and Dove (no Pigeons).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How do we determine the value `15` of `glyph.font`? Can this be adapted for `fontspec`?

Comment: And could this be made to work for all sizes?