# Copy theoremfont option from newtxtext

Tags: typography, amsthm, newtx

In Bringhurst it is suggested to use upright parentheses and punctuation in italic text.

The `newtxtext` packages allows for the option `theoremfont` which replaces figures, punctuation and parentheses in `amsthm` environments (which are my main source of italic text) by upright versions.

I would like to make use of this functionality, but I don't want to use `newtx` fonts. I tried looking into the package's source code and found the line `\DeclareOption{theoremfont}{\ntx@thrmtrue}`, but I can't seem to find where and how this boolean is used.

I was asked to include a MWE, however I don't have much to include. Here is an example of a theorem which should be changed quite drastically:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        At theorem with [brackets], \{braces\}, (parentheses), 1 or 2 numbers, and some punctuation\ldots!
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you make a MWE to give us something to start with?

Comment: The trick from `newtxtext` might not help you. It just uses relies on the fact that [ are upright in `\slshape` of this font `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}
\slshape [ \itshape [
\end{document}`

Comment: related questions: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/374064/upright-punctuation-independent-from-font-style https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86112/how-to-get-upright-parentheses-in-the-whole-document https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13048/upright-parentheses-in-italic-text

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}


\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{embrac}

\newtheoremstyle{plain}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {}       % BODYFONT
  {0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries} % HEADFONT
  {.}         % HEADPUNCT
  {5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        \emph{At theorem with [brackets], \{braces\}, (parentheses), 1 or 2 numbers, and some punctuation\ldots!}
    \end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This workaround, with `embrac` does not work if one uses `thmtools` to define a theorem style and, in the latter, uses `bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape`.