# Making normal brackets inside the theorem environment

Tags: theorems, italic

Suppose I have a simple code like the following one:

```
\begin{theorem}
  This is (theorem 1).
\end{theorem}
```

When you compile this code, you find that the two brackets are italized. Is there a way to make them normal ?!.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example which shows us which of the theorem packages you use and which style you selected?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no "theorem font" which should really have upright punctuation.  So the easiest way to make the brackets (or braces or parentheses) upright is to put them within `\textup` or math.

Comment: The [newpx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx) and [newtx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtx) packages have a `theoremfont` option that does what you're looking for

Comment: Can you type a code please? @mbert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `newtx` and `newpx` font packages have a `theoremfont` option that produces italic text and upright delimiters in the `plain` style of `amsthm`. In other settings, the "theorem" font family can be accessed with `\thfamily`. Here is a sample taken from `newtxdoc.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[theoremfont]{newtxtext} % or newpxtext
\usepackage{newtxmath} % or newpxmath

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is Theorem Italic: text numbers are upright---12345;
punctuation is in many cases upright (also, parens (), braces
\{\} and brackets []). What about question marks and
exclamations? Also upright! [These fit better with math
mode punctuation and figures, like: for all $x\in[0,1]$,
let $f(x)\coloneq \exp(\alpha x)$].
\end{theorem}

{\itshape normal italics: ()[]?!123}

{\thfamily theorem italics: ()[]?!123}
\end{document}
```

##### With newtx

[image: newtx]

##### With newpx

[image: newpx]

##### I do not recommend this

If you want to achieve this effect with other fonts such as Computer Modern, you can resort to hacks like the one below. It uses the [`embrac`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/embrac) package and borrows some of its internal code to define the `\hussein_embrac_text:n` command which makes the delimiters in its argument upright.<sup>*</sup> The command `\embracifytheorem{<theorem>}` redefines `<theorem>` so that it grabs its body and passes it to `\hussein_embrac_text:n`. This means it cannot contain any verbatim material.

<sub>*: We can't pass the body to the usual `\textit`, `\emph`, etc. because they are not "long" macros by default, i.e. they cannot contain `\par`.</sub>

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{embrac}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \hussein_embrac_text:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__embrac_tmpa_tl {#1}
    \embrac_replace_brackets:N \l__embrac_tmpa_tl
    \l__embrac_tmpa_tl
  }

\NewDocumentCommand { \embracifytheorem } { m }
  {
    \NewEnvironmentCopy { origenv_#1 } { #1 }
    \RenewDocumentEnvironment { #1 } { O{} +b }
      {
        \begin{origenv_#1}[##1]
        \hussein_embrac_text:n { ##2 }
        \end{origenv_#1}
      }
      {}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% you can adjust or remove these to your liking
\AddOpEmph{?}[0pt,1pt]
\AddOpEmph{!}[0pt,1pt]
\AddOpEmph{:}[0pt,1pt]

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\embracifytheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
This is \textcolor{red}{hacked} Theorem Italic: text numbers
are \textcolor{red}{not} upright---12345;
punctuation is in many cases upright (also, parens (), braces
\{\} and brackets []). What about question marks and
exclamations? Also upright! [These fit better with math
mode punctuation and figures, like: for all $x\in[0,1]$,
let $f(x)= \exp(\alpha x)$].
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image: cm]

Comment: Good. But these packages change the font entirely. This is not the usual font in tex.

Comment: @HusseinEid Yes these packages can do this because they define entirely new fonts. To do this with macros is difficult. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/423447/208544), for example

Comment: @HusseinEid See edit for a hack